# calculate multiplication factor to go from 1 to 100 in y attempts

Tags: arithmetic

I have `totalnumberofdays` and  `percentage on day 1`.  I have to incrementally grow the `currentpercentage` `every day` so that it reaches `100 percent` on `day n`

For ex:

If `totalnumberofdays` = 7, `percentage on day 1` = 1

`currentpercentage` would be equal to `percentage on day 1` the first day and then needs to grow incrementally.

```
Day 1   1 percent
Day 2   2 percent
Day 3   5 percent
Day 4   10 percent
Day 5   20 percent
Day 6   50 percent
Day 7   100 percent
```

How should `currentpercentage` be calculated for each day.

Comment: It is not clear what "grows incrementally" means. Can the percentage just grow by one every day, and then jump to $100$ on the last day?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: No, it should be uniformly and consistently growing but the percentage for a later day would always be greater than the prior day

Comment: Notice that what you may be calling the "multiplication factor" in your example is two the first day but two-and-a-half the next day, so it isn't constant. How variable do you allow it to be?

Comment: Linear growth or exponential ? ... or something else ? ... Your example is neither.

Comment: So, Simran, what do you mean by "uniformly"? As noted, your example is not uniform.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Exponential seems do it going by the example

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit  Exponential seems do it going by the example

Comment: It does not have to be exact. Just that it should reach 100% on day n. and grow each day.

Comment: Let $N$ be the total number of days, $x$ be the day number and $y$ the percentage. Then a linear relationship is given by
\begin{eqnarray*}
y=1+99 \times \frac{x-1}{N-1}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: For $y$ to increase exponentially 
\begin{eqnarray*}
y=\exp \left( \frac{(x-1) \ln(100)}{(N-1)} \right).
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Does the percentage each day have to be a whole number, as in your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is stated confusingly because growth is often calculated as a percentage, but growth in percentage uses this term twice. Are you sure you are not confused with the terms?

Apart from that, this just looks like an exponential function:

Define $p_1$ as the percentage on day 1, and in general $p_i$ the percentage on day $i$.
And a daily growth of (percentage) $q$

Then we have:

$$p_i = p_1 \cdot q ^ {i-1}$$

With formulas from your textbooks (or comments), you should be able to calculate $q$ from $p_1$, $n$, etc.

Comment: OP seems to be happy with this answer, even though it doesn't fit the example OP gives.